Trying to calcualte an analytical expression for the integration
K[rl_, rp_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Integrate[
     Simplify[Sqrt[rp^2 - (x + rl*Sin[theta])^2]*Sin[theta]], {x, 0, 
      rp - rl*Sin[theta]}, {theta, 0, Pi/2}], 
    rl <= rp}, {Integrate[
     Simplify[Sqrt[rl^2 - (x + rp*Sin[theta])^2]*Sin[theta]], {x, 0, 
      rl - rp*Sin[theta]}, {theta, 0, Pi/2}], rl > rp}}]

KResult = FullSimplify[K[rl, rp], Assumptions -> {rp > 0, rl > 0}]

I'm trying to calculate the following integral . Unfortuantely my laptop is slow or either my code is not great. Could you all please help me in solving this expression?

Integrate[Sqrt[rp^2 - (x + rl*Sin[theta])^2],    {x, 0, rp - rl*Sin[theta]}, Assumptions ->     {Inequality[-rp, Less, rl*Sin[theta], LessEqual, rp]}] gives a result
